Find an extension such that $\|\widetilde{f}\| = 2$
Let $\mathbb{R}^3$ be given the norm $\|(x,y,z)\| = |x| + |y| + |z|$ for $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $M$ be the linear subspace $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} : 3x - 2y + z = 0 \}$. Define a linear functional $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ by$
f(x,y,z) = x + y - z.
$
Find the norm of $f$ as a linear functional on $M$.Find an extension $\widetilde{f} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ such that $\|\widetilde{f}\| = 2$.
I got $||f||=4$, then define linear map $g ; M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g=\frac{f}{2}$, Now $||g||=2$ by the Hanh Banach theorem $\widetilde{f} : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ such  exits that is $g=\widetilde{f} $.
Is my answer correct?

$g$, and hence $\overline{f}$, are not extensions of $f$

@ChrisEagle So what is then?

I doubt you're supposed to use the Hahn-Banach theorem on R^3. Your functional f is defined on a 2-dimensional subspace of R^3. You can take a well-chosen unit vector u that is not in this subspace and define your extension to be equal to f on M and map u to 2.

We have  $$|f(x,y,z)|\le \|(x,y,z)\| $$ Hence $\|f\|\le 1.$ As $$f(1,1,-1)=3,\quad \|(1,1,-1)\|= 3$$ we get $\|f\|\ge 1.$ Thus we have obtained $\|f\|=1.$ By adding ${1\over 3}(3x-2y+z)$ we get
$$ f(x,y,z)= 2x+{1\over 3}y-{2\over 3}z$$
Let's define $$\widetilde{f}(x,y,z)= 2x+{1\over 3}y-{2\over 3}z$$ Then $\|\widetilde{f}\|=2$ as $\widetilde{f}(1,0,0)=2$ and $\|\widetilde{f}\|\le 2\|(x,y,z)\|.$
The extension is not unique. We can add other multiples of $3x-2y+z $ so that the maximal absolute value of the coefficients is equal $2,$ see the comments. However the extension which preserves the norm is unique and given by the original formula $x+y-z.$

It is easy to see that all extensions of $f$ have the form
$$ \tilde f(x,y,z) = x+y-z+\alpha(3x-2y+z)$$
with some fixed $\alpha$ that we may choose in order to make $\|\tilde f\|=2$. It is easy to see that $\alpha=1/3$ is a possible choice, so
$$\tilde f(x,y,z)=2x +y/3 -2z/3.$$

Ah, yes, $\alpha =-1/2$ also works.

I think with $\alpha=-1$ the norm is 3, since the coefficient of $y$ is $3$ then.
